# URL Routing show widgets.appharbor.com as widgets.com

Tags: url, routes, appharbor

Possibly a very silly question... I just don't know.

Assuming I have published a web application to Azure or AppHarbor, URL for the web app would be something like

```
http://widgets.appharbor.com
```

Assuming I own the following domain name:

```
http://www.widgets.com
```

How do I get `www.widgets.com` to display the application hosted at http://widgets.appharbor.com without using an iframe?

Furthermore, I don't want links within my application to be displayed as `widgets.appharbor.com/stuff`, they need to be displayed as `widgets.com/stuff`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Cloud Service or a Website in [Shared Website Mode](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-scale-websites/#sharedmode) you can use a [CNAME](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/) to point www.widgets.com to widgets.azurewebsites.net. I don't know how this works with appharbor, I assume they also support CNAMEs.

**Update:** Looks like AppHarbor also supports CNAMEs http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/1079-custom-domain-names